# UIWebView auto changing its height inside scrollview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to include *disqus* in my app *(commentaries API)* in Xamarin studio.

What I have now is `scrollview` in which programmatically added some text and pictures from `URL`.

I want to add UIWebView at the bottom of the `scrollview`, but the `height` of `webview` can be different, so it cannot be set.

Is it possible for `webview` to change its size because of `content size` 
(i don't want to have `scrollview` inside `scrollview`, so scrolling a `webview` is not an option).

I'm not asking about the solution, just some ideas if it's possible.
Thanks

Comment: I answered [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522203/uiwebview-height-calculation-in-swift/44608916#44608916), it shows how to make a web view fit its content, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible for you to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView, you can implement the same behavior (in terms of loading the URL and it's contents, etc.). WEKWebView exposes the scrollView property.

You can observe the "contentSize" property on that UIScrollView, and adjust your main scroll view's contentSize accordingly. Managing the contentOffset when this happens is a different thing all together.

Since your parent scrollView will always fully contain the webview, it won't scroll, leaving your user to be able to only scroll through the main view.

Comment: I just tested scroll inside scroll in iOS simulator - works not that bad as I expected.
Will check WKWebView, thanks

Comment: as long as you keep your master scroll's contentSize well synced, you'll be fine. Good luck.